# Selenium - Python - How to select dropdown option by part of the text

Tags: python, selenium, ghostdriver

I'm trying to select a dropdown option by part of the text.

How I would normally select text:

Select(browser.find_element_by_css_selector('selector')).select_by_visible_text("element text")

What I am trying to do:

Select(browser.find_element_by_css_selector('selector')).select_by_partial_visible_text("element text")

Comment: provide `html` sample code for required options

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do this with selecting via CSS. With xpath I think you can do it with something like this, but you have to change it to your xpath:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'yourText')]")
```

[Is there a CSS selector for elements containing certain text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520429/is-there-a-css-selector-for-elements-containing-certain-text)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe using xpath language?
Let's say you know object id, or other property it could be something like:

```
def select_option(element_text):
    xpath = '//select[@id=id]//option[contains(text(),' + element_text + ')]'
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
```